# HTML CSS issue regarding piwik iframe

Tags: css, matomo

I have 6 piwik iframe widget like this

```
<iframe id="iframe1"src="http://ip:portno/analytics/index.php?module=Widgetize&action=iframe&columns[]=nb_visits_returning&widget=1&moduleToWidgetize=VisitFrequency&actionToWidgetize=getEvolutionGraph&idSite=2&period=day&date=yesterday&disableLink=1&widget=1" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
```

I wasn't able to generalize these frames ... suppose I wanted to set the `min-height` & `max-height` values. Is it possible to set these?

Answer (score 0):

Use following way :

```
iframe {
    min-height: 200px !important; 
    max-height: 500px !important; 
}
```